# 301 Redirect - Query String to SEO URL after relaunch

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Before a relaunch pages were accessable as follows:

> ?page_id=10 // contact page

After the relaunch pages are accessable via seo urls. As of this `?page_id=10` has to be redirected to `/contact/`

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/(index\.php){0,1}$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page_id=10$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /contact/ [L,R=301]
```

However, for some reason this snippet causes an unlimited redirect

```
http://www.myurl.com/contact/?page_id=34
```

Ok, when inspecting the outcome url it's obvious but I am wondering why this snippet appends the query string to the url. I did not used a backreference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page_id=10$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /contact/? [L,R=301,NC]
```

`?` in target strips any query string.

Comment: This works. Got any idea why mine snippet appends the query string?

Comment: Yes because you didn't have `?` in target URL as I have

Comment: Ah, now I get what you mean with the last sentence ;)